# how to create a PID file for a java process

Tags: java, linux, bash, daemon, start-stop-daemon

I'm attempting to create a PID file like below:

```
LOCKFILE=/var/lock/ocr-trafficcop.lock
PIDFILE=/var/run/ocr-trafficcop.pid
JVM_ARGS="-Xms1024M -Xmx2048m -Dspring.config.location=/opt/app/configs/ocr-trafficcop/ -DserviceName=ocr-trafficcop -DAPP_ENV=int -Dlog.home=/opt/app/logs -Dservice.home=/opt/app"
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin"
PROGRAM=/usr/bin/java
PROGRAM_ARGS="$JVM_ARGS -jar $JAR_PATH"
#
. /etc/init.d/functions
#
daemon --user=$USER "$PROGRAM $PROGRAM_ARGS > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $! > $PIDFILE"
```

the PID file is empty though, so how do I create/populate a PID file ?

Comment: Java can [return its own pid](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html#current()), so the Java program can write its own PID file.

Comment: I think you want `|| echo $! $PIDFILE` there at the end (use `||` rather than `&` )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, it seems `daemon` doesn't really write pid files, from a brief search online.  However,something like this should work:

```
su -c "$PROGRAM $PROGRAM_ARGS >/dev/null 2>&1 &"
PID=$!
echo $PID > $PIDFILE
```

From here:

https://kiennt.com/blog/2012/06/29/run-program-and-generate-pid.html